# @ symbol valid in Unix username?

Tags: unix, authentication, ssh

A client has given me SSH access to their web server with the username firstname.lastname@email.com (my email address).

I've tried:

```
ssh firstname.lastname@email.com@555.555.555.555
ssh firstname.lastname+email.com@555.555.555.555
```

and several other combinations, but no luck.

I don't know anything about the server environment, other than that it's some flavour of Linux.

Before I come back to them saying it doesn't work, perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Just a guess, did you try `..name\@email.com@555...` ? Good luck.

Comment: That's a good suggestion - I've tried that and I'm getting permission denied following the password prompt. It may end up being the account, though.

Comment: I just tested this and it works on my system (Ubuntu). Pass -v to your ssh command and examine the output, it might set you on the right path.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I tried the -v option and output was much more helpful. I'm not a Unix expert, though - anything in particular I should look for, or would it be useful to post the output?

Comment: I think you'd be better getting in touch with the client at this stage. It sounds like something is wrong on their end. You can send them the verbose output and point them at this thread for more information.

Comment: Thanks, John. I'm glad to get some confirmation that I'm not just missing something. I'll follow up with them.

Comment: Even if it's valid, an `@‘ in a user name is very unusual (I've nebpver seen one).

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu Linux is happy to create a user with an at symbol in the name.  I created user bob@home and was able to log in using the syntax

```
ssh bob@home@myserver
```

as well as with the syntax

```
ssh -l bob@home myserver
```

Try using the -l switch to specify the username and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

If it's password authentication, you could always do:

```
ssh 555.555.555.555
```

then enter your username.

Comment: That sounds sensible. I tried that - I'm prompted for my password after that and am getting permission denied. Unless I'm missing something else, I'm guessing that means I'll need to talk to the client about the account.

Comment: yes, ssh is very picky about passwords, very easy to get locked out. Good luck.